# HTML - Email form mysql database trouble

Tags: html

I have the following code in index.html - We want to capture their name and email they enter in the forms into our mysql database

```
<form action="this_page.php" method="POST" id="contactsForm">
<div class="">
<center>
<input name="name" type="name" class="moonray-form-input" id="name" required="" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Name:" data-required="true">
</center>
<center>
<input name="email" type="email" class="moonray-form-input" id="email" required="" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Email:" data-required="true">
</center>
</div>
<div class="">
<center>
<input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Submit" id="submit1">
</center>
</div>
</form>
```

In this_page.php I have

```
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","secretsn","cPanelPassword");
$db_select=mysql_select_db("secretsn_email",$connection);
$sqlquery=mysql_query(USE secretsn_email;
INSERT INTO list_users(name,email) VALUES ("user1","password");
INSERT INTO list_users(name,email) VALUES ("user2","password");
SELECT * FROM list_users;);
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Your PHP logs are probably telling you exactly what the problem is.  SQL commands need to be enclosed in quotes like any other strings in PHP.  Even once you correct that, you're going to find that you are *creating the table* every time the form is submitted, which probably isn't what you meant to do.  You're also using hard-coded values to insert into that table, instead of the values being passed from the form.  Among other errors...  In all honesty, you should probably refer back to some introductory PHP/MySQL tutorials and start from there.

Comment: I have created it once, what code would it need to be to just import?

Comment: If you just want to insert a record, just use an `INSERT` statement.  You don't need to create the entire table just to insert a record if that table already exists.

Comment: I have updated my first post but that didn't work, sorry I am a newbie to this.

Answer (score 0):

From the API http://php.net/mysql-query

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Also, mysql_query was also deprecated.